# Unable to setup a connection to Amazon EC2 and run pig

Tags: hadoop

I have made an EC2 key pair and saved it to a location under my home directory on mac. Also I have changed permissions with 'chmod 600 /path/to/saved/keypair/file.pem'. Now I have followed the following instructions to run pig on EC2:

To set up and connect to a pig cluster, perform the following steps:

- Go to http://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/home signing
  in if necessary.
- Click the "Create Cluster".
- Enter "Data Science Assignment Cluster" or anything you wish as the Cluster Name.
- Uncheck the Logging box so that it is disabled.
- Scroll down to Software Configuration and select AMI Version 2.4.2  (We will be using Hadoop 1.x for compatibility with the version of Pig)
- Scroll down to "Security and Access" and select the Key Pair you created above.
- Scroll to the bottom and select "Create Cluster"
- On the next page, information about your cluster will be displayed.  It will begin in the "Starting" state and may take
  several minutes to startup completely.
- Once the cluster has started, you will see a "Master Public DNS" name of the form ec2-XX-XXX-X-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Make a
  note of this; we will refer to it as
  master.public-dns-name.amazonaws.com.
- Now you are ready to connect to your cluster and run Pig jobs. From a terminal, use the following command:  $ ssh -o
  "ServerAliveInterval 10" -i /path/to/saved/keypair/file.pem
  hadoop@master.public-dns-name.amazonaws.com

Having done this I only get a '>' prompt after hitting enter. Further if I write pig at the '>' prompt then I get again a '>' prompt in the next line i.e. no 'grunt' prompt. I have checked that ssh is installed on my mac and remote login is enabled for all users. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: @Sean: As I wrote in last paragraph, expected was 'grunt>' prompt to run pig, but actual was only a '>' prompt after executing the ssh command in the last step. I intend to run pig jobs interactively from the command prompt by connecting to EC2 instance.

Comment: Are you sure you're not already in Pig?

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to ssh to the Cluster's master instance, typing in "pig" in the prompt should result in something (either a grunt prompt or an error message of some sort). Did you make sure that pig is installed on the EMR cluster? (I don't see it in your directions)

Comment: That is what, I'm not sure if I am connecting to the cluster instance, as after type the ssh command and hit enter I just get a '>' prompt in the next line and nothing else. If I do Ctrl+C then I get back to the home $ prompt of home directory. 
Yes, pig and hive are both installed on my EMR cluster.

Comment: And when you type in pig in the instance's

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be generating from the path name of the EC2 key pair in the ssh command. My key pair was on desktop. So earlier, I tried executing the ssh command from the HOME$ prompt and mentioned the pathname of key pair file in the ssh command from the last step of the instructions as '/desktop/key-pair-filename.pem', and it dint work.

But then, at the terminal window I changed to the desktop directory. After that I executed the ssh command this time with simply putting 'key-pair-filename.pem' instead of '/desktop/key-pair-filename.pem' and it worked.